# How to convince colleagues to stop writing static classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns, static

I recently joined a new company. After working on some projects I noticed a pattern. Every project contains a lot of static classes. A lot of static `Helper` classes. `ApiHelper` `JsonHelper` `UmbracoHelper` `ContextHelper` `DbContextHelper`. Etcetera.

Now I know that this is not a good sign, and I tried to explain. They really want to learn, but I can't get myself to explain it right. Why should we avoid this static pattern? In our case we work in C# .NET.

---

Two reasons I could think of:

- Static classes avoid the single responsibility principal?
- Static classes are not testable?

---

### Edit

Thanks for the answers. My point was that indeed these `Helper` classes are a bunch of functions unnecessarily nested inside this `Helper` class. They do sometimes create stuff like a `DbContext` or read/write to the file system. It might be more readable but I am already seeing some technical depth because we over used them. A lot of the functionality should be nested inside a class that has one responsibility.

Example:

We have a `EventHelper` class which opens a new connection to the database (on every static method) and reads or writes data to the database. This also sync's all events from an API to the local database AND it writes images to Azure Blob storage. This is all called from a API Controller, which shouldn't directly control the flow of the business logic. It's a very long class, it has a lot of functionality which can be split up in to smaller classes making those individual functions testable on a OO way. They "kind of" split up readability be have a `public static void DoA()` and then have a couple of `private static DoAAlsoDoesB()` which is only called from `DoA()` making it a big mess, because we have a lot of methods which are called from one place. This isn't bad practise at all, it's good to split up code. But it's only a good thing when the collection of those methods (the class) has one responsibility. Not 10.

So I know why it's wrong, but I don't know how to explain it properly. And a lot of my arguments are rejected because well, a static helper class is easier to write then a properly constructed and thought out class which follows some of the basic OOP principles.

Comment: It seems to me the only argument you could raise against the practice is that C# has a nicer way to deal with lacking features: extension methods. Using those you can keep the extra functions more in context. But then again they may be harder to find when people need them. It smells a bit old school but there is no inherent problem with static helper classes when they are nicely separated in different domains (not just one static God class called Common which would be questionable). People who claim that "statics are evil" often mistake them for globals. They don't need to be global.

Comment: see [How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6630/31260)

Comment: omg i literally just this second was looking at the same thing.

Comment: The best solution to replace static classes and Singleton imlementations is to use Dependency Injection. It's the simplest way to preserve maintainability and tesability and allow shared instances. 1) It's not that static classes are not testable. Classes that depend on static classes are not tesable - you can't mock static dependencies.

Comment: 2) Static helper classes are almost always: a) named `Helpers` b) contain methods wher the author could not find a meaningful name in order to put it into a useful class c) are a messy collection where nobody knows what to expect. You only know the members you personally add. d) Untested. **3) Static members create a memory leak!**. Static types and members are considered as GC root. **They and everything they reference!** will never get garbage collected. This can cause severe memory leaks.

Comment: 4) Static instances violate encapsulation as they are globally accessible. In a well designed application you want to control accesibility and lifetime of objects. 5) Static members are good for constants 6) Otherwise static is not needed and leads to unmaintainable code as developers tend to use static code if they don't care/understand how to structure their application. It tends to get messy. 7) Modifying static dependencies always means tintroducing breaking changes - static dependecies are hard to maintain/extend

Comment: 8) Static methods or properties that return a reference to the database/IoC container are a variation of the Service Locator anti-pattern - there will be references all over the place totally out of control. As the application grows it will become totally unmaintainable. I have experienced products going down because of this. There will be a point when perfomance drops and/or you need to change/redesign the database - impossible. Youw ill throw coins to decide who has to touch the hell of code to fix bugs. All over the place = static. Static = unmaintainiable hell of sloppy code.

Comment: 9) If you seriously try to avoid static members you will have to think about the appliaction/class design more carefully. In 99.9% your application becomes better, cleaner more fun to work with. 10) I think we can go on and on. Static is like `null` or Null Pointers: the fact that they are there does not mean they are mandatory to use. They are a candidates to introduce sevre bugs and performance issues. You can always avoid static (and `null`).

Comment: I think the fact that you have to convince your mates is a proof of their lazyness. they like to go the easy way. Sometimes their likes don't understand architecture and OO principles. So it's easier to hide this deficit by making everything static and trying to convince everybody that it is a good thing. If you think about it then you find more reasons to avoid it (at least try hard). I assume we are talking about huge enterprise applications, not small scripts.

Answer (score 7):

Why is it not a good sign? If those methods are deterministic and have no side effects or the targets of side effects are passed in via parameters, then making them static methods is good idea.

By "deterministic and have no side effects", I mean that they create an output based on the input and constants, so the result is the same every time for the same input. Not having side effects means they do not read or write to global variables, files, https endpoints, databases etc.

If you have a class of methods that are all like this, then making them static means they can be directly accessed. This removes unnecessary levels of indirection and makes the code simpler to read and understand.

Of course if the above doesn't apply and eg `DbContextHelper` is creating database connections directly (rather than them being supplied via a parameter) then making them static is indeed a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question with more info

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR: static classes are not bad per se. Static classes can be used in non-optimal ways, but then so can everything else.

> Now I know that this is not a good sign

Static classes are a tool. As with everything else, they can be good and they can be not so good - you shouldn't just say "static classes are bad" without being able to point to an actual reason why.

> Static classes avoid the single responsibility [principle]

Are you seeing this in your codebase? Can you point to specific examples? If not, this isn't a reason.

Now, there is definitely a tendency for static classes (and particularly those called `FooHelper`) to be a grab-bag of unrelated functions which would violate the SRP, this isn't intrinsic to static classes - it's also perfectly possible to write both non-static classes which violate the SRP, and static classes which don't violate the SRP.

> Static classes are not testable

Static classes themselves are often in fact *more* testable than non-static classes, because they don't hold any state. But again, this is a question of the code you actually have in your codebase - are you able to write unit tests for your static classes? If so, not an issue.

The issue you may be thinking of here is that it can be hard to test classes which *make use of* static classes, because you can't do any dependency injection to mock out the behaviour of the static classes. But once again, whether this is a problem depends on your codebase and what's actually in your static classes - for example, it's very rarely a problem that you can't mock out .NET's `Math` class.

I think you need to invert your thinking here - rather than a general "static classes are bad" (which is honestly a bit [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult)), you need to come up with specific points and show how the use of static classes has contributed to those issues.

Comment: @Flater. If the static method is deterministic, there is no need to mock it. So this isn't a problem. If it's not deterministic, it shouldn't be static.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added more information, I did make assumptions in my question which I didn't meant to write that way. I don't think `static` is bad, the problem is how it's used in our code base

Comment: Your question is honestly now almost an entirely different question - because your problem is _not_ static classes per se, but just badly written code.

Comment: also the SRP is less important for static helper classes, since you can easily move functions around as you want, with no significant effects

Comment: .NET IO classes like File.OpenStream is a better candidate for a bad static library than Math. Since File.OpenStream containts integration. Which Math library does not

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself:

- Is there any state involved in these helper classes, or do they only contain pure functions?
- Do those classes have dependencies to other classes which might hinder your team to write unit tests?
- Do other classes depend on those static classes in a way they cannot be unit-tested easily any more?

If the answers to all three questions is "no", using static classes is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've edited my question with more information.

Answer (score 1):

The three answers you got so far show what an uphill battle you have on your hands.

in a hypothetical example you might asked to help with some code smells that have been highlighted by an analysis tool. A helper class has been written with a static method and now the tool is calling out for all the methods and the class to be made static. Rather than you know, make it an object.

This kind of thing leads people down the path of making everything static global functions... "OMG that is so COOL!" people interject "You *should* program like that! Static is good!!" ...with *global* state. NOT stateless you finish.

In terms of practical approaches I have found that "Testing" is one of the best arguments. Its hard to mock static functions, so if required to test things that use their helper classes those static functions can run into issues. Converting to an object with an interface solves those problems and convinces people not to use static.

However, its a bit of a fudge because I think people are leaning towards less mocking in tests these days.

I should add an explainer before i get 100000 downvotes.

"static, stateless functions have their place in functional programming, but the static keyword is often used as a get out clause for making OOP stuff work without making it OOP, introducing global state and tight coupling. Thus the 'don't use static' simple rule for OOP programmers".

Comment: "Thus the 'don't use static' simple rule for OOP programmers". Old school. I prefer the 'don't use OOP' simple rule these days. Static, stateless functions should take pride of place in all programming paradigms. You then switch to objects when you need state as objects are a brilliant way of encapsulating state. You introduce interfaces when that state can't be encapsulated within the object and that provides an abstraction around such side effects. And finally start with a test. Terms like "OOP" and "unit tests" just carry semantic baggage that get in the way. So ditch them.

Comment: double down and make em all anon functions

Comment: I think *"but the static keyword is often used as a get out clause for making OOP stuff work without making it OOP"* is the important part. @DavidArno: while I also agree with you that static, stateless functions are good in any programming paradigm, I also must agree with Ewan. I frequently see stateful/non-pure static functions created because people do not understand dependency injection properly, and just don't want to put in the effort to implement it when they should. I think that's what Ewan is trying to say in the last paragraph of this answer.

Comment: "double down and make em all anon functions" - On the other hand, if you assign such an anon/lambda function to a well-named variable that you can pass around or store as a class field, and let it capture a couple of local state variables at definition time, you get a nicely encapsulated closure that's basically a single-method object with a well-defined responsibility, created/designed with minimal ceremony. And clients can consume them polymorphically! Sometimes, when you double down on "avoid [what people think is] OOP", you find your way back to OOP.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, How is "people can't do OOP properly. So we'd best constrain them to just OOP." in anyway a sensible argument?

Comment: no-one is constraining people to OOP. its just that dotting your otherwise OOP with static methods != functional